# Is it possible to add the if condition inside `${ 'code here' }`

Tags: jquery

How can I insert the `if` condition inside of `${ }` using jQuery.

```
$('#inactive_list_body').append(`
<tr>
    <td>${value['name']}</td> 
    <td>${ if(value['status'] == 'false'){           
       value['identifier']}else{value['status']} }</td> 
    // ^^^^ Here I need to add IF condition
    <td>${value['reason_without_or_inactive']}</td>
</tr>
`);
```

Comment: What is `${value['name']}`? Is it a JSP EL expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator `?:`

```
 <td>${value['status'] == 'false' ? value['identifier'] : value['status']}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set that variable outside of your append method.

`let status = value['status'] ? value['status'] : value['identifier']`

Then you can use it as `<td>{status}</td>`

Answer (score 0):

`var === 'something' ? 'something' : 'not something'` construction may be used directly inside `${ }` block:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
   <p></p>
   <script>
       var a = 'a';
       $('p').append(
         `<tr><td>${a === 'a' ? 'a is a' : 'a is not a'}</td></tr>`
       );
   </script>
</body>
```